# Are you guys reserved (for the room)?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, slang, formality

So our school allows students to reserve private rooms for group study or coffee chat and these kinds of stuff. So the guy who checks the reservations always asks:" Are you guys reserved?"
Is it actually grammarly right to say so? He meant, "Have you guys reserved for the room?" But "are you guys reserved" do sounds more simple. Is it somewhat similar to " I am done/ finished" maybe?

Comment: *Are you guys reserved?* means "Are you guys shy?"

Comment: Sounds very odd to me, but in context it is of course clear what he means. If I were the reservation checker, I would say, “Are you guys booked in?” or “Have you guys made a reservation?” or “Have you booked yourselves in?” or any number of variations along those lines… but not “Are you guys reserved?”.

Comment: I also feel it's far from standard. I can't find 'be reserved' = 'having a reservation [at a restaurant etc]' in any online dictionary. But if the service is OK, don't mention it.

Comment: "Have you guys reserved?" would definitely be better than using *are*.

Comment: The normal way to ask this is "Do you have a reservation?"

Comment: I have reservations about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's grammatical, but it's not semantically correct. When we make a reservation, the adjective *reserved* applies to the room, not the person who made the reservation. So we say things like:

> The room is reserved for Joe.

The word *reserved* is also a past tense verb, and in that sense it can be used with a person as the subject, e.g.

> Joe reserved the room.

But in your example question, *reserved* is being used as an adjective, so this sense doesn't apply. When *reserved* is used to describe a person, it's a synonym for *shy*. Although in the context of your conversation, this is clearly not the intent, so most people would understand what he means (as you obviously did).

Some more common ways to ask the question would be:

> Have you reserved the room?
>   Do you have a reservation?
>   Did you make a reservation?